Movie where a girl tells a boy "I hope you die" during a camping trip, he goes missing, and they find him dead
A boy has a crush on a girl, but she rejects him or they have a fight...?
Either way, she tells him she hopes he dies.
The boy, the girl, the teacher, and the rest of their class go on a camping trip. I don't remember why, but a couple of kids get dragged away by a river's current, including the boy.
He's the only to not show up. They all start looking for him, and they found him impaled on a spiky bush / tree near the river.
I vividly remember the girl starts crying from the guilt and blames herself, and that they added his name along other dead kids' names on a stone memorial.
It was an American production. I watched it on TV on 2000.

You don't happen to remember the boy's name do you?

Any idea where they went camping?

@Möoz I only know it was an American forest :/
